# asp classic object to javascript object and make objects slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery, collections, asp-classic, slidedown

anyone here knows how to store ASP collection to Javascript collection? I got a code from my previous post but didn't put it to work i must have put the codes in the wrong places.

Im currently developing an app wherein once the document is ready each variable from the ASP colection will move down one at a time. I decided to use jquery to slide down each value since it has a slideDown event. but when i slide down the items from the collection slides down all at the same time. anyone here has an idea on how to do this or suggestions on a better way to do this?

```
<%

        Dim objDictionary, Key,searchWord, myVar,a,i, break
        searchWord = request.QueryString("searchWord")



        Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        objDictionary.CompareMode=1
        objDictionary.Add "Hello","hello"
        objDictionary.Add "Age","age"
        objDictionary.Add "height","height"
        objDictionary.Add "sample","sample"
        objDictionary.Add "words","words"


        Response.Write "<div id='toFall'>"
        if objDictionary.Exists(searchWord) then
            objDictionary.Remove(searchWord)
           a = objDictionary.Keys


            for i=0 to objDictionary.Count-1
            Response.Write( "<div class='fall'>" + a(i)) 
            Response.write("<br />")
            Response.write("</div>")

            next
            set objDictionary=nothing
        else 
            a = objDictionary.Keys

            for i=0 to objDictionary.Count-1
            Response.Write( "<div class='fall'>" + a(i)) 
            Response.write("<br />")
            Response.write("</div>")
            next
            set objDictionary=nothing

        end if      

        Response.write "</div>" 

'got this code from my previous post but didn't got it working  
        Sub CollectionToJavaScript(oCollection, sClientSideName) 
            Dim blnFirst
            blnFirst = True
            Response.Write("<" & "script" & " type=""text/javascript"">")
            Response.Write("var " & sClientSideName & " = {")
            For Each key In objDictionary.Keys
                If Not(blnFirst) Then Response.Write(", ")
                Response.Write( key & ": " & objDictionary(key) )
                blnFirst = false
            Next
            Response.Write("};")
            Response.Write("</" & "script>")
            Call CollectionToJavaScript (objDictionary, "myCollection")
        End Sub



        %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several mistakes in your code:

1. You were setting the dictionary object to nothing before you called your CollectionToJavaScript sub
2. You needed to use oCollection within the CollectionToJavaScript sub
3. The postioning of 
   Response.Write( key & ": " & objDictionary(key) )
   blnFirst = false

   ```
   <%    
   Dim objDictionary, Key,searchWord, myVar,a,i, break         
   searchWord = request.QueryString("searchWord")            

   Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")         
   objDictionary.CompareMode=1         
   objDictionary.Add "Hello","hello"         
   objDictionary.Add "Age","age"         
   objDictionary.Add "height","height"         
   objDictionary.Add "sample","sample"         
   objDictionary.Add "words","words"           

   Response.Write "<div id='toFall'>"         

   if objDictionary.Exists(searchWord) then     

       objDictionary.Remove(searchWord)            
       a = objDictionary.Keys               
       for i=0 to objDictionary.Count-1             
           Response.Write( "<div class='fall'>" + a(i))              
           Response.write("<br />")             
           Response.write("</div>")              
       next                    

   else   

       a = objDictionary.Keys              
       for i=0 to objDictionary.Count-1             
           Response.Write( "<div class='fall'>" + a(i))              
           Response.write("<br />")             
           Response.write("</div>")             
       next                   

   end if                

   Response.write "</div>"   'got this code from my previous post but didn't got it working           

   Sub CollectionToJavaScript(ByRef oCollection, sClientSideName)              
   Dim blnFirst             
   blnFirst = True             

       Response.Write("<" & "script" & " type=""text/javascript"">")             
       Response.Write("var " & sClientSideName & " = {")             

       For Each key In oCollection.Keys                 
       If Not(blnFirst) Then 
           Response.Write(", ")                       
       End If    
       Response.Write( key & ": " & oCollection(key) )     
       blnFirst = false       
       Next   

   Response.Write("};")             
   Response.Write("</" & "script>")             
   End Sub          

   Call CollectionToJavaScript (objDictionary, "myCollection")    

   set objDictionary=nothing      

   %>
   ```

Comment: thank for the reply i tried to do what you said and accessed the keys through this code


`<script type="text/javascript">
for (var key in myCollection) {
    alert("key is " + key + " and value is " + myCollection[key]); 
}
</script>`

but nothing happens

Comment: the purpose of that code you posted is to generate some clientside javascript code that places your serverside collection in a javascript object look at the source after you have viewed it in your browser eg var myCollection = {Hello: hello, Age: age, height: height, sample: sample, words: words};

Comment: yes i put it in the `<head>` part for me to test weather my javascript collection is being populated by my vbscript collection. what do you mean look at my source? sorry I think I don't get what you are talking about .

Comment: I meant you could verify that your javascript collection is populated by viewing your page source

Comment: yeah i see it now it did populate my javascript.. but how come i cant put jquery to add events to it? sorry I'm a bit new to ASP and I'm trying my best to understand it

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by what you are trying to achieve, I had a look at your other question, this jsfiddle may help you http://jsfiddle.net/Nicholas_Murray/bdeWE/

Comment: yes that is exactly what i wanted to achieve but i cannot access my collection in ASP. i want to add jquery events to make my collection inside my asp code slideDown. but when i add my jquery code inside the head part of my html it cannot seem to access my collection inside my asp code

Comment: you maybe need to ask another more refined question around this but bear in mind that any jquery you write should be at the bottom of the page to access any javascript clientside objects generated by your serverside asp